# Why Are There Three Words In Some Protocol Init Signatures

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, method-signature

When I write a new method signature in Swift, I follow the pattern:

```
func methodName(varName1: VarType1, varName2: VarType2, ...) {
```

Looking at some of the required protocol initializers, I have found a mystery third word in the signature.  For example:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
```

I understand that `aDecoder` is the param name and `NSCoder` is the type.  But what on *Earth* is `coder`?  For the love of all that's good, why does Swift have to make simple things so confusing?

Comment: because you don't read the documents? `coder` is label name, `aDecoder` is variable name, `NSCoder` is type name. all of these are properly documented in the official swift document.

Comment: I did read the docs and went through the tuts.  It wasn't too clear that the variable name wasn't the label.

Answer (score -1):

In this case `coder` is the parameter's external name and `aDecoder` is the parameter's local name.